# How to zoom Quartz Composer's viewer?

Tags: quartz-composer

I would like to zoom in and out in the viewer, my iPhone screens won't fit in my MB screen, and it seems impossible. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to zoom in Quartz Composer's Viewer window.

However, there's a workaround:

- Select all your patches, copy them to the clipboard, and delete them.
- Create a `Render in Image` patch and a `Billboard` patch.  Connect the `Image` port.
- Double-click on the `Render in Image` patch to go inside it.  Create a `Clear` patch, then paste your patches from the clipboard.
- Select the menu item Editor > Edit Parent.

Now you can adjust the `Billboard`'s `Width` port to change the size of the Viewer's output.